Does Angular i18n support changing language?
my goal is to change the language from English (United States) to Indonesia with a button.
Source Code

The problem is the tutorial do not demonstrate the feature to change language.
Why I want to use Angular i18n instead of creating custom helper?

I believe Angular i18n implement tree-shaking? So only the specific language will be downloaded by a browser.
I believe Angular i18n support Angular SSR? So it will render with the browser's language.

What I've tried:

add localize: ["id"] to the build key in the angular.json file and do ng serve.
In this case, i18n works.
 
angular.json
         "development": {
           "localize": ["id"]
           "optimization": false,
           "extractLicenses": false,
           "sourceMap": true,
           "fileReplacements": [
             {
               "replace": "projects/common/src/environments/environment.ts",
               "with": "projects/common/src/environments/environment.development.ts"
             }
           ]
         }




@jabaa sorry, to be specific, at runtime? i.e. the user click the Indonesia button.

The docs says that changing language during runtime is not possible. You need to build and deploy it (for example, with sub-domain names like en.example.com, fr.example.com). Then language can be changed just with routing.
There is another package for i18n called @ngx-translate, it supports this functionality.
However, there is one possible solution but it's deprecated. There is package @locl/core, that allows you load translation file manually. You can save prefered language in the local storage, for example, and then based on this load needed translation file. But still, you'll need to refresh the page to apply the changes.

IMHO, Angular i18n is too hard to use, and I had my fair share of nightmare from deprecated package, so I will not be using @ngx-translate. So, I decided to write my own implementation. Using import works well. The code example
